# Http request command line tool

Tags: http, https, request, swift3, httprequest

I am developing a Command Line Tool in Swift 3, i have this code:

```
let url = "www.google.com"
var request = URLRequest(url:url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

let task = session.dataTask(with: a){ (data,response,error) in

        print("REACHED")
        handler(response,data)


}
task.resume()
```

I cannot reach the task if i use "http://" or "https://" as prefix in any url, i am wondering if i need a App Transport Security plist, i already tried create a simple plist, anyone knows some if has a particularity for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When specifying a URL, you need the "scheme" (e.g. `http://` or `https://`).
2. The `url` is a `URL`, not a `String`, so it should be:

   ```
   let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
   ```
3. Yes, you need `Info.plist` entry if you want to use `http://`. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37552442/1271826 or [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http) or just search stack overflow for "`[ios] http info.plist`" or with `[osx]`.

   Note, in Xcode 8.1, console apps don't necessarily have a `Info.plist` file, so if you don't have one, you may have to add one by pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>:

   [image: add plist]

   update your target settings to specify the plist:

   [image: plist target settings]

   and then add the appropriate settings, e.g.:

   [image]
4. I assume where you have `URLRequest(with: a)` you meant `URLRequest(with: request)`.
5. You'll need something to keep the command app alive while you're performing the request (e.g. a semaphore or something like that).

Comment: Rob, thank you for your help, i'm using a plist now, but i still have request problems, i assume that problems is about the semaphore, but i'm using OperationQueue and BlockOperation to make multiple requests, i use that function to wait     operationQueue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished(), but i can't make requests, when i use HTTP or HTTPS, the operations doesn't work, can you help me again? Thanks

Comment: Okay, Rob, thank you, i will subclass the operation!